# Ngrx, subscribing to RouteParams emits an extra undefined value

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I'm using ngrx/router. In this case I want to "pluck" a route parameter called `externalId` and whenever `externalId` changes, I want to send the user to another route.

However, whenever I send them to another route, the `subscribe` block is executed again, **even if I don't have `externalId` in the new route.**

Any ideas why?

```
// Currently we are in the route: /contacts/:externalId
this.externalId$ = this.routeParams$.pluck<string>('externalId');
this.externalId$
.subscribe(id => {
    console.log(id); // this is printed twice, undefined the second time
    this.router.go('/start-page'); // this makes routeparams emit undefined
});
```